# Raspberry pi not detected using direct Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, connection

I am unable to use a IP scanner to find my raspberry pi when directly connected using Ethernet. (it worked like 1 month ago)

If i connect my rpi into my *router* and which is then connected to my pc through  an Ethernet cable. I can connect and detect the raspberry pi using the IPV4 address.

If i connect my rpi directly to my laptop (with SSH Enabled). My laptop does detect a new Ethernet connection and says that i have a new unidentified network. I then run ipconfig and i see that Ethernet 3 adapter is now active with a IPV4 address of: 192.168.137.2.

However when i scan: 192.168.137.0 - 192.168.137.255 I cant find the raspberry pi!.

Why is it that it works when connected through a router but not directly using Ethernet cable? Thanks

Comment: Is the raspberry pi configured for static IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect the Raspberry Pi and your laptop to the router it will give them each an ip address from its DHCP server. Seems it serves an ip range from the subnet 192.168.137.0/24 and give the laptop the address 192.168.137.2. If you disconnect the laptop from the router and connect the raspi to the laptop then there is no more a DHCP server that gives your devices a network configuration. It may be possible that they get a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) from ip address block *169.254.0.0/16* through [Zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking). Then you can find your raspi simply with name `raspberrypi.local` on the connection. Simply you boot the raspi and the laptop and try from the laptop

```
~$ ping raspberrypi.local
```

If you use a network scanner on this block it will scan 65534 ip addresses, hmmm...

Comment: Yes it was a DHCP server problem